# Cant retrieve record from large scale table row

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel framework.In my database records table have more then 400000 row. Now I want to retrieve record using some condition
 logic : 
need to match service id
need to match status

but my application cant retrieve data (unable to handle this request).
I am using query using this

```
foreach ($ven as $ven){
    $data = $ven->data;
    $record = $data ->records()->where('status','success')->get();
}
```

My status column already added in index.

Need suggestion

Comment: Its not completely clear what you are asking. Can you write a list of the things, with column names, that you are trying to match

Comment: `foreach ($ven as $ven){` ? or `foreach ($vens as $ven){` ? where is the service id

Answer (score 0):

First you need to keep statuses in int form not as strings. It would help you in filtering records easily.

And use `chunk` for handling large datasets. I suppose `$ven` is for venue. So, follow the code below.

```
DB::table('venues')
->select('venues.*', 'records.*')
            ->join('records', 'venues.id', '=', 'records.venue_id')
             ->orderBy('id')->chunk(1000, function($venues) {
    foreach ($venues as $venue) {
        // your logic
    }
});
```

**Note:** I used query builder instead eloquent. That is because query builder is faster than eloquent.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to access related records in loop could create [**N + 1**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-select-query-issue) problem

> [As per official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) *When accessing Eloquent relationships as properties, the relationship data is "lazy loaded". This means the relationship data is not actually loaded until you first access the property. However, Eloquent can "eager load" relationships at the time you query the parent model. Eager loading alleviates the N + 1 query problem*

You could eager load your related data as

```
$results = ParentModel::with('records')
                        ->where(...) /* If there are any filters for ParentModel */
                        ->get();
```

For eager loading only 2 queries will be executed to get your data for main model and related model. Each row in `$results` will a collection of related records which you can iterate to list details of each related object.

To get filtered rows of related model you could modify `with()` method as

```
$results = ParentModel::with(['records' => function ($query) {
                            $query->where('status','=','success');
                        }])
                        ->where(...) /* If there are any filters for ParentModel */
                        ->get();
```

To get filtered rows of ParentModel on basis of related records you could use `whereHas`

```
$results = ParentModel::with('records')
                        ->where(...) /* If there are any filters for ParentModel */
                        ->whereHas('records', function ($query) {
                            $query->where('status','=','success');
                        })->get();
```